# Azure Pipelines: How do I show a group of related checkboxes as parameters and then pass as array?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Azure Pipelines: How do I show a group of related checkboxes as parameters and then pass as array?

This is how I know you can show checkboxes for pipeline parameters:

```
parameters:
- name: Package One
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: PackageTwo
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: PackageThree
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: PackageFour
  type: boolean
  default: false
```

How can I group them and pass as an array to another template?

I'm thinking as far as design, maybe the ones that are checked add to array to be passed?

```
- template: 'Templates/yetanothertemplate.yml'
  parameters: 
    parm1: ['PackageOne','PackageTwo','PackageFour']
```

Comment: You don't. That is not a supported capability.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with:

```
- template: 'Templates/yetanothertemplate.yml'
  parameters: 
    parm1: ['Test1:${{PackageOne}}',Test2:${{PackageTwo}},Test3:${{PackageThree}}]
```

Then on the called template:

```
Template1.yml
steps:
- ${{ each value in parameters.parm1}}:
  - powershell: |
      $arrPkg = '${{value}}'.Split(':')
```